# Should I use docker with app services rather than app service direct?

Tags: asp.net, azure, docker, .net-core

I am new to the world of docker and azure app services.

Proposed by a colleague:

ASP.net core app --> Create docker image --> Azure container registry --> Azure App service.

My experience:

ASP.net core app --> Deploy to Azure App service

We have been recommended to use a container with an app service layer on the top of this container.

I was wondering what are the main benefits of doing this rather than just deploying an app service direct?

With the app service we can scale out, scale up, add a load balancer use web api management etc, but not clear why I would add another layer but placing a container under it?

The app itself is a simple API asp.net core application - we have separated out the SQL server part into PaaS SQL.

Any guidance would be great as to the reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deploying as windows container, then I don't see benefit. In my opinion, it will actually lead to unnecessary complexity

If you are deploying as linux container, then there are couple of advantages

- You incur lower costs as no windows licensing cost needs to be given
- Performance increase as linux does not have lot of unwanted baggage

Comment: Hi thanks for that - but if the app is a asp.net core app - would the above moving it to linux container using docker incur less charges?

I mean adding a web app service ontop to allow CI/CD pipelines etc isn't it just better to deploy to an app service direct?

I think it's adding to the complexity as you suggested but I don't understand containers that well

Comment: Yes, moving an asp.net core app to linux container will incur significantly less costs. Containers are hosted on some VMs and if VM is Windows server, then you will have to pay extra for windows licensing. Apart from that, windows containers are having very big base images (running in GBs) which are not good. For containers, always prefer linux over windows